# Issue connecting R with Teradata

Tags: r, teradata, rjdbc

I'm having issues connecting R with Teradata.

```
library("RJDBC")


drv = JDBC("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver";"C:\\...\\terajdbc4.jar,
           C:\\...\\tdgssconfig.jar")

conn = dbConnect(drv,"jdbc:teradata://dbserver","user1","pwd1")
```

When I try to run the connection part I get the following error message:

```
GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: UserFile parameter null)

....

Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please note that I have already check that the .jar files are in the right path and that R has the proper rights to access them. I have looked at similar questions on the Teradata Community forum but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This means specifically, the **tdgssconfig.jar** library is missing in your classpath, even through you believe it's there.